# How to use Route 53 domain with SiteGround

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, nameservers

I have a domain I registered through Route 53 and have used to host static website with AWS. Now I would like to use it with SiteGround hosting.

SiteGround shows me the account DNS with IP (ns.XXX.XXX.us (00.000.000.000)). So I went to 'Registered domains', clicked my domain, and edited the name servers to the one given by SiteGround. I also deleted the old Hosted Zone for my domain.

Right now, visiting the domain results in a 'This site can't be reached' message with '[my domain]'s server IP address could not be found DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.' message.

I have no idea what I should try now. What have I missed?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: It can take awhile, 24 - 48 hours sometimes, for DNS to propagate

Comment: Can you share the real domain name?

Comment: Sure. www.seungjaeryanlee.com

Comment: Did this require any resolution or did you just need to wait? Normally AWS propagation is nearly instantaneous, but I'm seeing the same slowness.

Comment: What was the resolution to this?